# best approach to call 2 services methods from scheduler in one transaction

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, transactions, scheduled-tasks

I have scheduller:

```
@Component
public class MyScheduler {

    private static final long INIT_DELAY = 1L;
    private static final long DELAY = 10L;

    private final UserService userService;

    public MyScheduler(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void schedule() {
        ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        scheduledExecutorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(this::process, INIT_DELAY, DELAY, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    private void process() {
        userService.process(new User("Bill", 20));
    }
}
```

In UserService I save new user and throw exception:

```
@Slf4j
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    public UserServiceImpl(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public void process(User user) {
        log.info("Start process...");
        userRepository.save(user);
        methodWithException();
        log.info("End process...");
    }

    private void methodWithException() {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

As a result, the user is saved despite the exception. To fix this I can apply several ways:

1) Add `@Transactional` above  `private void process()` and change this method to `public`

2) Add `@Transactional` above `public void process(User user)` method in `UserService`

In first case it not helps because `process() witn @Transactional` calls from the same class.

In second case it helps.

But if I add new Service, for example LogService:

```
@Service
public class LogServiceImpl implements LogService {

    private final LogRepository logRepository;

    public LogServiceImpl(LogRepository logRepository) {
        this.logRepository = logRepository;
    }

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public Log save(Log log) {
        return logRepository.save(log);
    }
}
```

And change scheduler to:

```
@Component
public class MyScheduler {

    private static final long INIT_DELAY = 1L;
    private static final long DELAY = 10L;

    private final UserService userService;
    private final LogService logService;

    public MyScheduler(UserService userService, LogService logService) {
        this.userService = userService;
        this.logService = logService;
    }

    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void schedule() {
        ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        scheduledExecutorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(this::process, INIT_DELAY, DELAY, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    private void process() {
        User user = userService.process(new User("Bill", 20));
        logService.save(new Log(user.getId(), new Date()));
    }
}
```

**Question**:

`userService.process` call in one transaction and `logService.save` cals in another transaction. I need call bouth services in One transaction.

I see two ways:

1) inject `logService` to `userService` and call `logService.save` in `userService.process` method

2) Create new service for example `SchedulerService` with method `process` and inject `userService` and `logService` in this service. And call in bouth services in one transaction.

In first case I get new dependency in `userService` and this can violate area of responsibility  in this service. Why should the service know to pull another service

In second case I need create additional service (one more class)

It would be ideal to be able to annotate the internal Schedulers method `@Transactional` annotation. I know that this can be done using **cglib** instead **proxy** but I use proxy.

Which approach would be better?

Comment: cglib is a proxy as well. Difference one is interface based other is classbased, but still both are proxies. Use the `TransactionTemplate` in the `process` method to wrap both methods in a single transaction. Or move the `process` method to a different class and simply mark the method as `@Transactional`.

Comment: @ M. Deinum "Or move the process method to a different class and simply mark the method as @Transactional" - this is just my second case - "2) Create new service for example SchedulerService with method process and inject userService and logService in this service. And call in bouth services in one transaction.".

Answer (score 0):

Imho, this is a good usecase for `PlatformTransactionManager`, with or without `TransactionTemplate`.
For this I'm going with a pure `PlatformTransactionManager` solution.

If you're on `Spring Boot` you'll have it as a Bean by default.

```
@Component
class MyScheduler {
    private static final long INIT_DELAY = 1L;
    private static final long DELAY = 10L;

    private final PlatformTransactionManager txManager;
    private final ConcurrencyService userService;
    private final LogService logService;

    MyScheduler(
            final PlatformTransactionManager txManager,
            final ConcurrencyService userService,
            final LogService logService) {
        this.txManager = txManager;
        this.userService = userService;
        this.logService = logService;
    }

    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void schedule() {
        final ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        scheduledExecutorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(this::process, INIT_DELAY, DELAY, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    private void process() {
       final DefaultTransactionDefinition definition = new DefaultTransactionDefinition(PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW);
       final TransactionStatus tx = txManager.getTransaction(definition);

       try {
          final User user = userService.process(new User("Bill", 20));
          logService.save(new Log(user.getId(), new Date()));
          txManager.commit(tx);
       } catch (final YourException e) {
          txManager.rollback(tx);
       }
    }
}
```

---

Using `TransactionTemplate` will "eliminate" the need of explicitly invoking `commit` and `rollback`.

You can have `TransactionTemplate` as a Bean, or you can construct it manually from a `PlatformTransactionManager`, as I've done here.

```
final TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(txManager);
transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() {
    @Override
    protected void doInTransactionWithoutResult(final TransactionStatus status) {
       final User user = userService.process(new User("Bill", 20));
       logService.save(new Log(user.getId(), new Date()));
    }
});
```

Comment: Don't. Instead use the `TransactionTemplate` to wrap both methods in a transaction. Saves the overhead of manually doing all the commits/rollbacks etc.

Comment: @M.Deinum I don't agree at all. I prefer explicitly seeing when committing or rolling back. But I suppose it's a matter of taste. That's why I wrote with/without.

Comment: We can agree to disagree, but also the Spring team recommends to use `TransactionTemplate` before considering `PlatformTransactionManager`.

Comment: @M.Deinum I'll add an example with that.

Comment: @ M. Deinum It always scares me to use explicitly something that can be used with aspects. And what do you say about my options? (Create a separate service for the sheduler which will both be called service). Now I have such an implementation - one service injects another service. and calls the method of this service at the end of its method (which is in the transaction). And I thought to rewrite it so that there was a separate service for the sheduler and in it to encapsulate the call of both services in a separate transaction. Therefore asked a question.

Comment: @ip there is nothing to be scared about. Extract the method only if it makes sense.

Comment: @LppEdd If I need create test for this class, what should I do? mock `PlatformTransactionManager`?

Comment: @ip696 You don't need to do that at all. Spring already gives you everything, see https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#testing-tx

Comment: @ip696 have you decided which approach to take?